# Is there a way to know the options with which OpenCV was installed?

Tags: opencv, tbb, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

I read that when installing OpenCV you can specify a series of options (use of CUDA, TBB, NEON, etc).

My question is, suppose I have access to a (ARM) machine, in which OpenCV is already installed. Is there a way to learn which options was OpenCV installed with? (for example does it use CUDA, etc)

Comment: [`getBuildInformation()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga0ae377100bc03ce22322926bba7fdbb5)

Comment: There is generally an executable called `opencv_version` that comes with **OpenCV** (depending on how it was installed), so you can run `opencv_version -v`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks! I used that too, it is very useful. One question, does this also give info on NEON or VFPV3? I dont notice any of these in the outut of opencv_version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can use [getBuildInformation()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga0ae377100bc03ce22322926bba7fdbb5).

```
import cv2
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

In case of cpp,

```
...
std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << std::endl;
...
```

This will return information about cmake settings, version control, compiler flags, third-party libraries etc related to opencv installation.

Comment: Thanks! I just read about this. Seems what I am looking for. However I found out that in the particular installation I have, opencv for python is not installed, so I cannot do this. I guess I ll have to write a C++ equivalent of this to check this out

Comment: @KansaiRobot yes. I have added a small update. It will do.

Comment: Does this function give info on NEON or VFPV3?  I have gotten the output but nothing is mentioned about those two. (TBB is mentioned as "Parallel Framework")

Comment: It should have shown. I am not sure about the reason in your case. In raspberry-pi it shows info on NEON, VFPV3

Comment: You mean is shows as "NEON off" ?  Thanks for all your help. I have decided to go on, install (I think it would take a day?) opencv on a jetson AGX I have hear and then check what messages it gives